# Azure pipeline gate - Invoke Rest API Error - The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management

I have an azure pipeline the is deploying an API. After the deploy I have a gate that will call the API and check for a Successful status before deploying to the next environment.
The problem is every time this gate runs I get this error :

```
2021-05-27T19:42:30.3298765Z GET https://management.azure.com/https://apim-myapi.azure-api.net/api/Vehicle/Makes?year=2017?api-version=2020-09-01.12.0
                Response Code: 0
                Response: An error was encountered while processing request. Exception: {"error":{"code":"MissingApiVersionParameter","message":"The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests."}}
Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (type WebException)
                Evaluation of expression 'eq(root['status'], 'successful')' failed.
                
Exception Message: Error parsing API response into a JSON object. (type DistributedTaskException)
```

I have tried adding a different version to the URL I am using, but I always get the same error.
Even though it looks like I am passing the value that it wants!

Anyone used this gate method? How does the versioning parameter work?

UPDATE : Adding in the gate settings that I am using :

[image]

Comment: Looks like you add the api-version to your api. Maybe do a request to your api via (inline) powershell instead?

Comment: Run this api in postman to see if there will be a 400 error.  error 400 may be a problem with the api url itself.

Comment: I can call the API fine from the test portal in azure. It doesnt require the API version. Its only when I call it from this task in the gates. I can also call it externally outside of azure, and it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

What I don't understand is why your request looks like this:

`GET https://management.azure.com/https://apim-myapi.azure-api.net/api/Vehicle/Makes?year=2017?api-version=2020-09-01.12.0`

Is this one call or two calls? Because it seems to me that you are making two requests and receiving two errors.

So the first one is `https://management.azure.com` and this is [APIM REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/) address. For this call when you call it like that you will get `MissingApiVersionParameter` error, because it requires you to specify `api-version` parameter.

On the second hand you are also calling your API `https://apim-myapi.azure-api.net/api/Vehicle/Makes?year=2017?api-version=2020-09-01.12.0` (which based on your description is what you want to do) and you are getting
`Evaluation of expression 'eq(root['status'], 'successful')' failed.` which is clearly an error from api policy.

`api-version` parameter has nothing to do with your API call. So remove `https://management.azure.com` and `api-version` from your call and just call `https://apim-myapi.azure-api.net/api/Vehicle/Makes?year=2017` (this is how request to your API should look like) and focus on the `expression failed` error.

Comment: Im not sure where that first part of the call is coming from. I added above the settings that I am using for the gate. Perhaps the URL suffix and parameters needs to change?

Comment: OK I fixed the call. It is now returning a valid response. I created a generic endpoint instead of just calling the APIM. Now I am having trouble with the return value evaluation, but I will ask that in another question

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Azure Resource Manager connection type, which is why the API URL was not correct.
I changed it to a generic endpoint, and in my URL suffix and parameters I just added "/api/Vehicle/Makes?year=2017". That call now succeeds.